# Need to generate offset value in BIG QUERY dynamically using user parameter for pagination in looker

Tags: google-bigquery, looker

I am trying to create a big query sql for pagination in looker. The number of rows that will be displayed at a time will be 5000 which is fixed and user inputs will be provided for page number.

Below query executes fine in BQ. This is a simple query

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
select distinct column1 from <table> order by column1 limit 10 offset @page
"""
USING 1 AS page;
```

the parameter page will be provided using user inputs.

However, when i try to execute query below, I get an error and its not executing

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
select distinct column1 from <table> order by column1 limit 10 offset 5000 * @page - 5000
"""
USING 1 AS page;
```

Here I am trying to dynamically calculate offset values based on the page that user will provide.
For example,

page 1 will show first 5000 rows.
page 2 will be 5000*2 - 5000 = 5000
page 3 will be 5000*3 - 5000 = 10000 so on.

However, the error I am getting as below

Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string  `<query>` order by column limit 5000 offset 5000 * @page - 5000 `, Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "*" at [1:19]

Looks like I cant use multiply etc in offset values or is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do your calculation inside `USING` as in below example

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
select distinct column1 from <table> order by column1 limit 10 offset @page
"""
USING 5000 * 1 AS page;
```

Comment: Thank you @mikhail. This didn't strike me.